# sql server license

Tags: sql-server-2008, license

I look for an instance of sql server but I dont know what kind of license I need or how many user(?)

my situation : 
I have 15 (can going to 100) user. 
we will have some apps that will use the db but that will never be something big, I know that we doesnt have 100 users and never will.
Only for local use.
And the traffic is not excessiv (maybe if they can use the db at the same time but I dont think that will be so much problematic if we have a little slowness.)

but the program they use can have the same user (I think). (using the same db_user on each instance of a program)

*** I dont know how thats work. (dbUser/concurrent)

can you help me about that.

what kind of license I should get? Probably just Standard but what kind, by user, by processor?

I need more than the express version, mostly because of database size. theres probably other reason like maybe for corrpution recovery, backup compression.

Tank you

Comment: In SQL 2008 you don't have backup compression, except in Enterprise. It's included in Standard only from SQL 2008 R2, if I'm not wrong. Are you sure that maybe Workgroup or Web edition are not enough? Did you do an assessment of your needs? How much space you need, how many CPUs, how much RAM..etc. You can compare SQL Server editions [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx).

Comment: From your comments to answers you've received to this question, it sounds like you may be confused about how per user (CAL) and per CPU licensing works. Can I suggest you either pop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) or call Microsoft.

Comment: I will look at the chat, but before I will check server config and what I need (I try to know space requirement but I'm not sure that my calcul is good, most of time its so much. I try to calculate how much by line*estimate nbr of line.)

Did theres a site where you can calculate db size, maybe by table (you said every col of a table and their type and that give you the max size of a line)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.  Questions on licensing should be referred to the vendor, and an answer obtained in writing from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with standard edition, Server/CAL model.  The server license is around $1800, each CAL is about $150.  Only buy CAL's if you actually need them.

Single CPU licence is about $5000.  That model would work for you if you have 1 CPU in your server but lots of cores to actually do the work.  A CPU is for the actual physical socket (unless the license model has changed again...)

An advantage of the server/cal model is that you only have to buy one cal per user, no matter how many servers you have running in your organization.

Comment: if I dont know how many userwill use the database?

and if its that kind of price, 20 user and we're over the 5000

Comment: You must have a starting figure.  10?  20?  And the 5000 is per CPU.  How many CPU's will you have?

Comment: if I understand, A CAL its for any computer that will use the db?

Comment: I'm not sure what do u mean by CPU.

Comment: the price is one time or by year

Comment: if I have a dualcore, did I need to buy 2CPU liscence?

Comment: Nope. With SQL 2008, cores are NOT counted towards a licence. It is the big old chip that fits in a the socket. Does not matter how many cores are in it. However, not many production class servers only have one CPU.

Answer (score 4):

Licensing is "per CPU" or "Server/Cal".

- Per CPU is for any number of users
- Server/CAL requires 1 CAL per user. Not concurrent users: any user who will use SQL Server

It is all contained here in [this MS PDF](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sql%20server%20licensing&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CE0QFjAB&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/E/48E9A4EB-125A-49CB-9644-169B82C45611/SQL2008R2_QRG_2011.pdf&ei=DknFTuPBL9DGtAaR8dT3Cw&usg=AFQjCNFbWHURoyEwdNmIy3DdPn6M_0iIIw&sig2=z6S91RkscriADFUYURoNEQ)

Comment: yeah , but I still dont know what to do. maybe a little more explaination or better, OPINIONS, like a what would you do?

Comment: I'd go for the cheapest legal option. There is no "opinion", only fact. Read the PDF.

Comment: I would add to gbn's comment...CAL's apply to devices as well as people.  Any hunk of code that has to connect to the database would require a CAL.

Comment: what will happend if you dont have enough CAL. like you have 5 and 10 apps call the db at same time

Comment: Then you are illegal. It is no concurrent users but all users who will ever connect. I said that already and so does the PDF